# Can you add additonal fields to new Parse.User? [javascript]

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Am I able to add additional values  to the new.Parse.User, such as address or hair color? Or are those values reserved just for username, password, email, and phone?

Like so:
[Javascript]

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", username);
user.set("email", email);
user.set("password", password);
user.set("address", myaddress);
```

If not how would you go about doing this? Would you need to create a User Profile Class for ever new user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation on retrieving objects](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-retrieving) should explain this.

You can add any fields you want with the set method.

```
var user = new Parse.User();

// set the properties of the user
user.set("username", username);
user.set("password", password);
user.set("email", email);

// Create a custom field for the user (there is no limit to the number of custom records)
user.set("score", 0);

// other custom fields could be added like this:
// user.set("user-status", "I am happy");
// user.set("nickname", "super-user");
```